# Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 13 7390

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop that came with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed. There are Dell repos for drivers that issue updates, but only for 18.04.

I recently updated my laptop to Ubuntu 20.04, but now realize that I don't seem to find Dell repos for 20.04. Anyone knows if there are repos and where to find them?

Comment: Please note you may not need additional repositories. Those from Dell exist while the additional drivers, firmware, etc. isn't added to the kernel. Two years passed since the original release and the one you have now a several kernel updates.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I see. Is there a way to confirm this? That is, that all the drivers I need are indeed part of the Kernel?

Comment: Well, Dell not updating the PPA is a good indication. I suggest you search or ask around in the Dell forums, they're usually responsive.

Comment: Yeah I already tried leaving some comments in relevant thread... But no reply yet :(

Comment: Running standard Ubuntu installed fresh from a live USB on a Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop. No issues. I never felt the need for any Dell repository.

Comment: @vanadium Nice. Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: I am noting a strange "micro-stuttering" issue, where the laptop freezes intermitently for a few seconds, and then responds again. This happens frequently, almost every minute.

Comment: I also have some issues with a flickerling display. None of these were issues on 18.04